# Confusions about if statement and strcmp with Strings

Tags: c, string, if-statement, strcmp

Here, I need some help in understanding the strings. I have a buff, which is flushed and then passed to a UART function. This buffer is now updated nad holding some value. I need to check the 5th byte of the buffer. What confuses me, I have written in code below.
Please take a look.

```
int main()  
{  
  char buff[8];
  memset(buff,0,8);  

  /*  
       This buff is used by some UART function, and hence is updated by UART  
       This buff now holds some data. And now, I need to check the 5th byte it is holding.  
  */   

  if(buff[4]==0x04)  //will this work? or I need to use if(strcmp(buff[4],0x04))  ???
  {  
    //Do some functionality, for an example    
    printf("True");  
  }  
  else  
    printf("False");  

  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: You need to check the 5th byte of the buffer and compare it with what? The character 0x04, the character '4', or something else?

Comment: its hex value 4. i.e. 0x04. Not with any character

Comment: Your code is then correct as noted in the answer. Note however that the commented-out code is very wrong -- strcmp(buff[4],0x04) will treat 0x04 as a pointer, not as data, and will most likely crash.

Comment: Your code is fine, if you are sure that you have read 5 bytes so buff[4] is valid. Of course it would be fine to check the first 4 bytes too, but that is another story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct, yes.

Using `strcmp()` for this would only work if you know that the `'\x04'` character is followed by a `'\0'` string terminator. Since it looks like binary data,  it would be very strange to use `strcmp()`.

You are *not* in any way comparing "strings", so using `==` is fine. In C, a "string" means "a (pointer to a) 0-terminated array of `char`". That is not waht you're dealing with, so any lessons learned about how to deal with strings don't apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. Its a binary data only.

Comment: I thought I should Never use the == operator to compare the value of strings! Strings are char arrays. The name of a char array acts like a pointer to the string (just like other types of arrays in C). That caused the confusion

Comment: Character arrays and strings are not the same thing. Strings are stored in character arrays but strings need a NUL terminator and tend to contain only printable character codes. A character array has no such restrictions.